# prove G has a normal subgroup of order 3

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have a question asking me to show that G has a normal subgroup of order 3 if it contains two elements of order 3. I have thought about this for a while now and cannot find a way to proceed.

Comment: Hint: what do you think the normal subgroup has to be, if the elements of order 3 are $g_1, g_2$? What happens when you conjugate a subgroup?

Comment: You mean *exactly* two elements of order three?

Comment: yes I think the question means that

Comment: also I am a little confused what you mean by 'conjugate a subgroup'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be an element of order 3. Then $H = \langle a \rangle$ is a subgroup of order three, containing namely $\{e_{G}, a , a^{-1}\}$. Let $g \in G$. Then $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of order three. The elements of $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$ must coincide or else $G$ will contain more than two elements of order three. Hence, $H = gHg^{-1}$ for all $g \in G$, which shows that $H$ is normal.

Comment: can you explain why $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$ must coincide, why would G contain more than two elements of order 3 if they did not.

Comment: Your problem is wrongly copied. It should have said G contains EXACTLY two elements of order three. We have $H = \{e_{G}, a, a^{-1}\}$. $gHg^{-1} =\{e_{G}, x, y\}$. Now $a$ and $a^{-1}$ are already two elements of order three in G. So if $x$ is different from $a$ and $a^{-1}$ then you have another element of order three, which contradicts the assumption.

Comment: thank you for clarifying